# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{32}\frac1{n^2}=1 + \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{9} +\dots+ \frac{1}{1024}<2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that 
$$1 + \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{9} +\dots+ \frac{1}{1024} <2$$

I know that the denominators are perfect squares starting from that of $1$ till $32$. Also I know about this identity 
$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} > \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} > \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$
But I am not able to implement it
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{2^5} \frac{1}{k^2}
&\leq 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{2^5}\int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{1}{t^2} dt\\
&=1+\int_1^{2^5}\frac{1}{t^2} dt \\
&=2-\frac{1}{2^5}\\
&<2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

We know $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} > \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ Adding for $n =1,2,\cdots,31$, we get, $$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{4}$$ $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} > \frac{1}{9}$$ $$\vdots$$ $$\frac{1}{31}-\frac{1}{32} > \frac{1}{1024}$$Adding gives us $$\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{9} +\cdots +\frac{1}{1024}< 1-\frac{1}{32}$$ $$\Rightarrow 1+\frac{1}{4}+ \cdots+\frac{1}{1024}< 2-\frac{1}{32} < 2$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well what should we do in case of when series is less than 1.8 I don't think this summing or identity will help

Comment: Can this help? n/n+1<n+1/n+2

Comment: Yeah instead of 2

Comment: @LokeshSangewar **IF** other question **THEN** new post, please.

Comment: Well I just need a hint for that not complete answer.. That's why not print a new one.... Well I'll try first

Comment: @juniven I did not add 1 in the second last expression.

Comment: @Rohan  Its okay now. You don't need to simplify it since you need to add by 1 both sides

Comment: @LokeshSangewar For the smaller bound, take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623327/an-inequality-1-frac122-frac132-dotsb-frac1n2-lt-frac53).

Answer (score 1):

For $n>0$, we have
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

and by sum,
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{31}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{32}<2$$

Comment: Well since it involves integration... It's kinda complex for me to understand

Comment: @LokeshSangewar Is it easier now.

Comment: Yes.... It is. Lol